# Unable to run D program on mac system when using dependency

Tags: d, dmd

I am pretty new to D language. I am working on existing code developed by others. Previous developers were using linux environment to build and run the D Application.
I am trying to do the same in MAC as it is my local environment.

Here is how my jub.json file looks like

```
{
    "name" : "dsmasher",
    "description" : "Hello World - A minimal DUB bundle.",
    "dependencies" : {
        "d2sqlite3": "~>0.9.7",
        "botan": "~>1.12.9"
    }
}
```

The program is very simple

```
import std.stdio;

int main () {
   return 0;
}
```

But when I build it throws following errors.

```
/Library/D/dmd/src/druntime/import/object.d(3440,23): Error: template memutils.refcounted.RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem).RefCounted.opCast does not match any template declaration
/Library/D/dmd/src/druntime/import/object.d(3440,49): Error: template memutils.refcounted.RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem).RefCounted.opCast does not match any template declaration
/Library/D/dmd/src/druntime/import/object.d(3441,39): Error: template memutils.refcounted.RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem).RefCounted.opCast does not match any template declaration
../../../.dub/packages/memutils-0.4.9/memutils/source/memutils/vector.d(790,10): Error: template instance object.__equals!(const(RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem)), const(RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem))) error instantiating
../../../.dub/packages/memutils-0.4.9/memutils/source/memutils/helpers.d(71,27):        instantiated from here: opEquals!()
../../../.dub/packages/botan-1.12.9/botan/source/botan/tls/server.d(689,38):        instantiated from here: opEquals!(RefCounted!(Vector!(RefCounted!(X509CertificateImpl, ThreadMem), ThreadMem), ThreadMem))
/Library/D/dmd/bin/dmd failed with exit code 1.
  ^^^ Terminated, exit code: 2 ^^^
************  Build terminated.  ************
```

I am using dmd compiler for this.
Please help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in Botan. According to Travis CI, their build fails with [the same message](https://travis-ci.org/etcimon/botan/jobs/308953168).

Comment: So to get the Hello World example to build: remove the  "d2sqlite3": "~>0.9.7" and "botan": "~>1.12.9" dependencies. They aren't needed for Hello World :)